# How to force stop launched process even running on front?

Tags: android, android-service

I am writing a task manager service and need to force close any running process, lets say browser, I tried using killBackgroundProcesses,restartPackage,killProcess but none of these force closes process ( e.g browser ) when process is on **front** else they are working.

I want to **force stop** the **process** even when process is running on **front**.
What should I do now ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem like you.I used a method in the service that killed the background process.So whenever i need to kill process that is running in the foreground i just brought my Activity in the foreground.So the process want to kill automatically goes background and can be killed with killBackgroundProcess.

But surely this is not really a good practice

Comment: can I send any process ( say browser ) to background ? , because whenever I send running process to background my service kills that process without coming on foreground.

Comment: you can.If you bring your process in foreground then previous foreground process will automatically goes back

Answer (score 3):

Solved, here is the code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
Appmgr.killBackgroundProcesses(RunningP.processName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Rony. I have to add that this solution may spawn another clone task of the background task, since your flag is set to `NEW_TASK`. I set my flag to `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, and my Activity had the `android:launchMode="singleTop"` attribute so my Activity is the single task spawned for the application. Also there was not need for the `CATEGORY_HOME` category, worked without it for me (for now).